# Printing two dimensional array with brackets and commas

Tags: java, arrays, string, eclipse, methods

So I am trying to print a two-dimensional array with brackets and commas. Here is my code:

```
public class ArrayPrinter {

    public static int printArray(int[][] arr) {
        {
            System.out.println("["); {
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                        System.out.print(arr[i][j]);
                        if (j < arr.length) {
                            System.out.print(", ");
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("]");
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] oneD = {5, 6, 7, 8
        };
        printArray(oneD);
        System.out.println(); {
            int[][] twoD = {
                {2, 4, 6, 8},
                {8, 7, 9, 1},
                {3, 5, 1, 2}
            };
            printArray(twoD);
            System.out.println();
        }
        int[][] twoD2 = {
            {1, 2},
            {3, 4, 5},
            {6},
            {7, 8, 9}
        };
        printArray(twoD2);
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void printArray(int[] arr) {
        System.out.print("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i]);
            if (i < arr.length - 1) {
                System.out.print(", ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("]");
    }
}
```

This is my result now:

```
[5, 6, 7, 8]
[
2, 4, 6, 8
8, 7, 9, 1
3, 5, 1, 2
]
[
1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 
6, 
7, 8, 9, 
]
```

This is the result I want:

```
[5, 6, 7, 8]
[
[2, 4, 6, 8]
[8, 7, 9, 1]
[3, 5, 1, 2]
]
[
[1, 2]
[3, 4, 5] 
[6]
[7, 8, 9]
]
```

I want the arrays to be printed with brackets and commas but each one-dimensional array should be on a separate line.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second loop surround the `[]`

```
public static int printArray (int[] [] arr) {
    System.out.println("["); {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("[");
            for(int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) 
            {System.out.print(arr[i][j]); 
            if (j<arr[i].length-1) {
                System.out.print(", ");}
            }
            System.out.println("]");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("]");
    return 0;   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why you don't use [**`Arrays.toString(oneD)`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int[])) and [**`Arrays.deepToString(twoD)`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString(java.lang.Object[])) like this :

```
int[] oneD = {5, 6, 7, 8};
int[][] twoD = {{2, 4, 6, 8}, {8, 7, 9, 1}, {3, 5, 1, 2}};
int[][] twoD2 = {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6}, {7, 8, 9}};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(oneD));
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(twoD));
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(twoD2));
```

This can show you :

```
[5, 6, 7, 8]
[[2, 4, 6, 8], [8, 7, 9, 1], [3, 5, 1, 2]]
[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Don't forget to import your library :

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

Comment: I guess because sometimes you want the colums to line up visually.

Comment: I tried that, but the columns did not line up; it was all just one line. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

Simplest implementation of your 2D array method. Just make it use the 1D method:

```
public static void printArray(int[][] grid) {
    System.out.println("[");
    for (int[] arr: grid) {
        printArray(arr);
    }
    System.out.println("]");
}
```

Quick note here is that I don't put an empty line between the rows of a 2D grid. If you want your exact output just add an empty `println()` inside the for loop:

```
 public static void printArray(int[][] grid) {
    System.out.println("[");
    for (int[] arr: grid) {
        printArray(arr);
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("]");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    System.out.print("[");
    for(int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(arr[i][j]); 
        if (j<arr.length) {
            System.out.print(", ");
        } else {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    System.out.print("]");
}
```

Replace your two for-loops with the ones above. You need to append and prepend the brackets to every array inside the main array. Hope this helps!